# Passing in name in function and using it as a value in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create several (10) dataframes on information on different subject exams. For instance, I will need Science, English, Math, etc.

Expected output:

```
     Exam  Student ID Final Score
0    SXRX   000000000          99
1    SXRX   000000001         100
2    SXRX   000000011          99
3    EXRC   111111110         100
4    EXRC   111111100          99
```

Current inputs:

```
>>>SXRX_dl_df
...
     Student ID Final Score
0    000000000          99
1    000000001         100
2    000000011          99

>>>EXRC_dl_df
...
     Student ID Final Score
0    111111110         100
1    111111100          99
```

I have created a script that performs the data analysis for Science. My script has this kind of structure:

```py
def subject_df(subject, subject_dl_df):
    # logic

    df = pd.DataFrame()

    df['Exam'] = subject

    df['Last Name'] = subject_dl_df['Last Name']

    # more logic

    return df


SXRX_df = subject_df('SXRX', SXRX_dl_df)
```

I was hoping to genericize it so that I could apply every subject into it (perhaps from a list), however, Python currently won't let me use the parameter I pass in as a value for the column. The code above gives me back NaNs for `df['Exam']`. It works fine if I apply `SXRX_df['Exam'] = 'SXRX'` afterwards, but that's more ad hoc and I was hoping for a better solution.

Right now, the subject name is in the source filename itself, if that helps.

How can I reapply this script 10 times for different subjects and ensure the right subject is under the `Subject` column each time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. What are your expected inputs and outputs? From what I can gather, it seems you may want to redesign your data handling process, but I'm not sure how

Comment: The problem might be index alignment, because when you create the df, you don't specify the index. what happens if you change the order of the two lines of code: `df['Last Name']...` (put this one first) then `df['Exam'] ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch the assignment order of df, you can assign the subject within the function.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Last Name' : ['Farmer','Smith','Fisher'],'ID' : [10001,10002,10003]}
sxrx_d1_df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

def subject_df(subject, subject_d1_df):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Last Name'] = subject_d1_df['Last Name']
    df['Exam']=subject


    return df

SXRX_df = subject_df('SXRX', sxrx_d1_df)
```

This will produce the following dataframe:

```
    Last Name   Exam
0   Farmer  SXRX
1   Smith   SXRX
2   Fisher  SXRX
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: As Ben T. mentioned, trying to assign a string to a dataframe with no index will result in NaN. Switching the order of assignment provides an index, and subject can then be assigned correctly.